# Improving performance of animations in sigma.js

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, sigma.js

Good day!
Today I faced performance problem in my web-application.

Application is quite simple: It draws a large connected graph (about 2k nodes), and animates dots moving from one node to it's neighbor.
I used library for working with graphs `sigma.js`, and it's plugin `sigma.animations`

When I added about `10` moving dots it was okey - smooth animation,
But when I reached about `1k` dots fps become so low so all moving was in one frame and of course zooming and scrolling worked very lagly.

All code works in single page, so all calculations are done by browser I guess.

My question is: is there any way to seriosly update performance? May be using backend tools? The task is about to draw railway system of some country, and in real-time showing train's coords.

If I can't do such an web-application using `js + canvas`, can you advice me another technology?